# Auto register user with HWIOAuthBundle

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

I am using `HWIOAuthBundle` with `FOSUserBundle` with success.

When I go to the `/login` page it redirects me to the Google Accounts, authorizes and returns back to the register form with filled data (except password fields).

Is it possible to auto register user with ommiting register form ?

In this case we do not need password because of authentication with Google Account.

How should I achieve this scenario ?

Comment: Did you use FOSUBUserProvider or some custom service in order to get redirected to registration page? Can you explain that little bit more? I am unable to get redirected to registration page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A question is a bit old, but better later than never.

You just need to create a **custom provider** - if you want to integrate the bundle with FOSUserBundle you need to override the [FOSUBUserProvider](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Security/Core/User/FOSUBUserProvider.php) class.

In [HWIOAuthBundle/Security/Core/User](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/tree/master/Security/Core/User) directory you may find all providers that are available in the OAuthBundle out of the box.

To create new user while *connecting* you just need to override loadUserByOAuthUserResponse() method of the FOSUBUserProvider (or EntityUserProvider, etc.) provider class. As you may see, default method throws an exception if the user is not found in database, you just need it to call userManager and create new entry.

This is exactly the same situation as with FOSFacebookBundle intergration (if you did so).

Hopes this answer helps you (especially it may sound a bit chaotic).

**Edit:**
I've posted a [blog post](http://www.osmialowski.co.uk/symfony-2-oauth-a-better-way-to-integrate-hwioauthbundle-with-fosuserbundle/) explaining the integration process.

Comment: Thanks Andrzej, I had many other tasks to do so I still didn't done it yet, so you answer may be helpful.

Comment: @hsz Take a look at this reference page at Github (https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/reference_configuration.md) it may give you more knowledge about how this bundle works (and it's working perfectly).

Comment: @AndrzejOśmiałowski above link is broken can u provide the new one

Comment: @Hunt oh, you meant configuration reference from my comment. Here's the working one: https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/internals/reference_configuration.md.

Comment: @hsz I'm preparing a blog post regarding the issue covering user creation, banned accounts, etc as I've received plenty of requests to explain the use case. Will update my answer when the stuff gets ready.

Comment: @hsz better late than never: http://www.osmialowski.co.uk/symfony-2-oauth-better-way-integrate-hwioauthbundle-fosuserbundle/ :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this [gist](https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697)

or this [tutorial](http://www.diegocaprioli.com/adding-hwioauthbundle-to-your-symfony2-project/)

Answer (score 1):

There's a good walk-through on how to integrate HWIOAuthBundle and FOSUserBundle to achieve the automatic user registration *and* update here, which might be worth a read:

https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697

Answer (score -4):

Yes of course.

You should handle a response from google and authorize user manualy something like:

```
// authorize 
$token = new OAuthToken(null, $user->getRoles());
$token->setUser($user);
$token->setAuthenticated(true);

// update session
$session = $this->getContainer()->get('session');
$session->set('_security_secured_area', serialize($token));
$session->save();
```

after user was authorized redirect to the call page by user

Comment: This case ommits creating new user. I have no idea how to create it from this point.

Comment: This is not what @OP was asking for in my humble opinion. Have no idea why this answer was marked as correct to be honest ;)

Comment: This is not what OP was asking for. The posted code only creates a token and store it in session, it's not about the persistence.